# Setting the datasource of a WPF Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm very new to WPF, and am trying to set the datasource (which the WPF Grid doesn't have as a property) of my grid to take a List. Does anyone have any code examples of how to do this. I have googled it, but can't find any really good examples.

(Oh, and can anyone suggest a good site for all round WPF Code examples?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to a WPF Grid, you can't bind it to data; it's meant for layout purposes only; you might want to look into one of the controls that inherit from ItemsControl, such as ListView.

The property you'd bind your list to, is called ItemsSource.

Comment: Do you have to call any other methods after setting the ListView ItemsSource property?

Answer (score 1):

The other control you might be thinking of is the [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx)

There's also the [`DataGrid`](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) (Note old link) in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) which implements a lot of the same functionality as the WinForms `DataGridView`